# Speeding up exponential moving average in python

Tags: python, pandas

I found pandas ewm function quite slow when applied to huge data. Is there any way to speed this up or use alternative functions for exponential weighted moving averages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by definition, these are functions that are computationally intensive on huge datasets.

So there is very little hope to speed this up. Something you can try is to save the corresponding series as a `.csv`, do the smoothing in Pandas, and then merge back to your huge dataframe.

Sometimes that can help as carrying a large dataframe in memory back and forth is costly.